# ReadLine (Buffered reader) does not work in a loop

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bufferedreader, readline

I'm writing code in Intelij. readLine does not correctly read the input (puts a line break at the end of the line), which is why the next readline does not work (becomes automatically empty).
Code:

```
public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = reader.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            else list.add(s);
            s = reader.readLine();
        }

        for (String str : list) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

If important: LF separator and UTF-8 encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug in IntelliJ IDEA](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293951/Console-readLine-skips-input-in-202211). The fix is already available, please [update](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).